# Android Studio wont import androidx.annotation.NonNull. Compiles fine though

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

My Android Studio with API 29 wont import `NonNull` from

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

It displays `NonNull` as red, for Java or Kotlin. However, everything compiles fine. The problem is that intellisense does not work correctly.

How to fix this? Couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @CrazyCoder wont work

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),